# CodeIgniter query not being inserted into database

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my function:

```
function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')                        
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('members', $new_member_insert_data);
        return $insert;
    }
```

My table is named "members" and I can connect to my database to pull out data I manually type into it.  Any thoughts about why this doesn't insert my data?  All of the field names are correct and the data is in the POST.  I echoed it to check out both of these things.  Here is my form:

```
echo form_open('engineering-resources/login/create');

echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', 'First Name'));
echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name', 'Last Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Login Info</legend>
<?php
echo form_input('username', set_value('username', 'Username'));
echo form_input('password', set_value('password', 'Password'));
echo form_input('password2', 'Password Confirm');

echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Acccount');
?>
```

There is a route for the form action:  `$route['engineering-resources/login/create'] = "resources/login/create_member";`

Here is my controller:

```
function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        echo 'hello';
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['title'] = 'Please Resubmit Your Information';
            $data['main_content'] = 'resources/signup_form';
            $this->load->view('templates/main.php', $data);
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('login/membership_model');
            echo $this->db->last_query();

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['title'] = 'User Area';
                $data['main_content'] = 'resources/logged_in_area';
                $this->load->view('templates/main', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('resources/signup_form');         
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: since you are using routing, are you reaching the controller? try to echo anything in the `create_member` if so, then try echo this `$this->db->last_query();` after the insertion to see what was the sql query, copy it and try it manually from phpmyadmin

Comment: This query works in my database editor

Comment: Nothing is being echoed in create_member.  Wait yes, it is.  So there is a problem in my logic.

Comment: hmmmm, you said you can interact with the DB? and select stuff? ok then, make sure that the DB user in your `config/database.php` has `insert` privilege!

Comment: How do I set that in config/database.php?  I don't see anything about insert?

Comment: no, go to your phpmyadmin, and then privileges and check the privileges of the user used by CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, try to prepare your array in the controller:

```
$this->load->model('login/membership_model');
$new_member_insert_data = array(
    'first' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->input->post('password')                        
);
if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member($new_member_insert_data))
```

And your model:

```
function create_member($data_arr)
{
    $insert = $this->db->insert('members', $data_arr);
    return $insert;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enable profiling by using the following directive:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Then you can see if your query is executed and if it's correct.

Comment: I get back  INSERT INTO `members` (`first`, `last`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('test', 'test', 'test@test.com', 'test', 'test') which matches my field names and the data.  Other thoughts?

Comment: @shummel7845: are you saving your password in plain text?!

Comment: For the moment, only while I develop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm going to learn something myself here, but you are using a syntax I'm not familiar with in one of your `if()` statements, so I'm going to bring it up to see if it helps.  Feel free to educate me if I'm wrong.

I assume your first `create_member()` function is in your `membership_model`, and that the controller function you exhibit is the one you re-route to: 'resources/login/create_member'.

In your controller you use:

```
if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
```

and I don't see `$query` defined anywhere, so I expect php to be comparing the returned boolean from the `create_member()` function to an undefined variable: `$query`.  Maybe this is a common way to assign a variable and run a function all at once (that I'm unfamiliar with), but to trouble shoot, have you tried to call `create_member()` without this 'advanced' syntax?

```
$query = $this->membership_model->create_member();
if($query)
        {
            $data['title'] = 'User Area';
            $data['main_content'] = 'resources/logged_in_area';
            $this->load->view('templates/main', $data);
        }
```

I also agree with ifaour...you aren't technically passing anything to be inserted into `membership_model/create_member()`, so you may try to grab it in the controller function per his example.  I'm not sure the POST array that is passed from the form to your controller gets passed to the model automatically.

These two steps might help you out.  To recap: simplify your call to `$this->membership_model->create_member($data);` and put the POST array into an array (`$data`) in your controller.